Relationship between existence of solutions to similar PDEs?
I'm interested in the following linear homogeneous partial differential equation:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = f(x,y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} 
$$
for a general function $f$.
I would like to show that a solution $u(x,y)$ exists, but I don't want to impose unnecessary regularity conditions on $f(x,y)$. However, I have one extra piece of information: For some positive real number $k>0$, there is a global solution to
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = k f(x,y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} 
$$
Does this help me at all with showing the existence of a global solution to the first PDE?

For this particular family of PDEs, well-posedness is given by the well-posedness of a system of ODEs via the method of characteristics. $k$ doesn't affect the well-posedness of the ODEs so that doesn't seem like it would be an issue

What about the analogous question for ODEs, then? Suppose $\frac{d}{dx} y(x) = f(x,y)$ has a global solution for any initial condition $y(0)$. Does that imply $\frac{d}{dx} y(x) = k f(x,y)$ has a global solution for any initial condition $y(0)$? I am looking to avoid conditions on $f$ like Lipschitz continuity if possible.
